# Bootstrap containter-fluid do not expand in tablet portrait

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, landscape-portrait

I'm trying to disable responsive under 940px this way

```
.container{
  min-width: 940px !important;
}
```

Doing this (and other changes in media Q) works fine in desktop and also in tablet, but if i turn the tablet in portrait mode the fluid container doesn't expand..it seems to keep around 60% of the available width. The fixed container (not fluid) works well.
Container-fluid and also bootstrap carousel behave identically.
This only happens if I change the container above.
There's a relation with the non fluid container and the fullwidth version?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle of the html and css relevant to your issue??

Comment: Thanks Andrew! After a night of good sleep i got illumination! I must declare also the min-width for the container-fluid! if not, it expands to the device width that can be lower than 940 (like in my case) !

Comment: Can you write about your solution in the answer box provided. This is preferable than making edits to the question, which leave the question in the "unanswered" queue.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I must declare also the same min-width for container fluid (and other 100% elements) because on mobile device they keep the max width of the device, which can be lower than my fixed-width container.

```
.container, .container-fluid, all-elements-with-100%-width{
  min-width: 940px !important;
}
```